# Can spark's driver memory be set to something other than a number of gigabytes?

Tags: apache-spark, jvm, pyspark

I am launching pyspark and I can supply the `driver-memory` parameter via command line to specify the maximum memory usage by the driver. In Spark's online documentation, they often just use a value like `1g` or `2g` as examples, but I am not sure if it's legal to use `3300m` or `4500m` as the value.

I think this parameter is related to the jvm's `Xmx` parameter which must be a multiple of 1024m which is more of a reason why I am confused.

Does spark's driver memory parameter properly handle something other than a number of gigabytes?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a multiple of 1024m

Comment: @ShuaiYuan How do you know? Can you link to some resource?

Comment: I cannot find any doc saying "you can do this". The easiest way to confirm is to start a cluster with a driver memory which is not a multiple of 1024m.

Comment: In fact, I often set it (and also executor memory) to some "odd" value (e.g., 22300m) to maximise the utilisation of instances.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it works. Looking at the documentation and my previous experience, you can set the driver-memory in mbs also. Eg: 512m

See: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

**Properties that specify a byte size should be configured with a unit of size. The following format is accepted:**

```
1b (bytes)
1k or 1kb (kibibytes = 1024 bytes)
1m or 1mb (mebibytes = 1024 kibibytes)
1g or 1gb (gibibytes = 1024 mebibytes)
1t or 1tb (tebibytes = 1024 gibibytes)
1p or 1pb (pebibytes = 1024 tebibytes)
```